# Which are the best lightweight, non-solar, camping lanterns available?

Tags: camping

What features should I look for in lightweight, non-solar, camping lanterns? What are the best brands available?

Comment: Hi Sam, this forum is a question and answer site that is aimed more at how to do something as opposed to gathering opinions.

See this page for what types of questions to avoid: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

And see this page for the kinds of questions this site is aimed at: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JonathanLandrum While this question does indeed need some TLC, I would say it is not opinion based. There is only 1 specific answer to "What brand is the most lightweight"

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the mention of specific brands. Whichever one is the most lightweight will likely have a specific brand, but mentioning a bunch of brands is irrelevant to the question. I basically restated the title in the question.

Comment: @Loduwijk - it remains a shopping question though, and one where the answer will change with time rendering any answer here and now pretty useless.

Comment: The weight (of reasonably light models) will be dominated by the batteries, so the lightest will be dim and/or have a short runtime due to low battery capacity. Brightness and battery capacity are often given in the title of product listings, so can be used to find candidates for light weight ones.

Comment: @JonCuster "]shopping question"? Debatable. "Which one is the lightest?" is not the same as "What brands are known to be reliable?" There are plenty of well received questions here which are more "shoppy" than "which is lightest?" As for the answer changing with time, that does not make it "pretty useless," not at all. I doubt there is a new record changing the answer to this question every few months. Even if it does change occasionally, so what? Someone reads this in a few years and thinks the second-lightest is actually the lightest. Questions improving ultralight gear should be on topic.

Comment: @JonCuster However, don't mistake my previous comment to mean that I think the question is perfect, of course not. Just that it's worth answering and not worth shutting down. If you don't like these kind of questions, you could do a self-answered Q&A about finding ultralight gear in general. I usually Google "ultralight X" then click all the results and compare the price and weight. It seems trivial, but many people seem to need it explained to them.

Comment: I think the edits make it a better question, but it will also still likely become obselete sooner than other questions. If the question was about 'what to look for in' I'd have no doubts it would be reopened sooner.